# How to use python to convert "Truyền Kiếm" to "Truy\u1ec1n Ki\u1ebfm" and vice versa?

Tags: python-2.7

I am new to Python and trying to convert "Truyền Kiếm" to "Truy\u1ec1n Ki\u1ebfm" and vice versa. I've tried u"Truyền Kiếm".encode("utf-8") and get an error Unsupported characters in input. Please help.

Comment: Have you [told the interpreter](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) that your source is in utf-8? Also what, you you mean convert? Both are literals that are only exist in source.

Comment: If you are new to Python, why are you starting with Python 2? The [Stack Overflow Python community](http://sopython.com) overwhelmingly [recommends](http://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F) starting with Python 3, as does [python.org itself](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3). Version 3 is the present and future of the language, while 2 is the past. In learning 2 first, you'll pick up many bad habits that will need to be corrected when you learn 3 (which you'll need to do eventually), so it's much better to start with 3 first, then learn the differences in 2 later.

Comment: One of the major advantages of Python 3 is the fact that all strings are Unicode.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Maybe the way I ask is not correct, but how can I "translate" one into another?

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a solution after searching Google.

```
import json
print json.dumps("Truyền Kiếm")
print u"Truy\u1ec1n Ki\u1ebfm"
```